# How to create unicommerce API client in java using myeclipse and get response?

Tags: java, myeclipse, webservices-client

http://support.unicommerce.com/customer/portal/articles/1467822-api

this api i have to use to make a client. i tried to make the client using myeclipse's WebService Client creation option but wsdl validation was failure. please give me a way to make it.

Comment: This is very little information to go on. If you wish to get help then you must include as much information as you can. Some things that might help are the MyEclipse version, the OS and version, the exact steps you're taking (including which type of web service client), the WSDL you're trying to use and the error you're encountering. That's probably a minimum. Don't expect others to search for information that you can provide directly.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are referring to this WSDL: https://staging.unicommerce.com/services/soap/uniware16.wsdl?facility=01. If so, try saving the WSDL in a local file and then creating a client. I had no problem with MyEclipse 2015 Stable 1.0 and generating a client for JAX-WS.

Comment: Hey Thanks for the information. now i am on one step ahead. all the classes regarding this wsdl prepared automatically in one package. now i want to start making a sample.  Please can you give me a sample code that send GetPurchaseOrderDetailRequest and get a response back through sample validation(with sample username and password) on that api. It will be very helpful for me. Thanx alot in Advance.

Comment: amit pls read more about SOAP and using the client. You can generate a sample response from the WSDL file.